# Can't bookmark a page in Firefox

Tags: keyboard, firefox, bookmarks

I haven't been able to bookmark a page using keyboard shortcut `command + D` or star icon in the address bar for about a month.

At first, I assumed this shortcut might've been removed in upgrade to version 25.0.1, 26 or 27.0.1 but after going through their change log at `http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/` I couldn't find any of that.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this without losing my existing bookmarks?

Comment: Is the "Bookmark this Page" menu item greyed out under Bookmarks? Also, do you have bookmark syncing turned on?

Comment: Nope, it's not greyed out. Bookmark sync is turned on. I tried resetting firefox, fixing bookmarks file as described here: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-add-change-or-save-bookmarks#w_fix-the-bookmarks-file, nothing worked. I made my bookmarks bar visible and tried to drag a link to it, didn't work.

Comment: Can you follow these instructions and get your bookmarks backed up? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer

Comment: I was able to resolve this by exporting the bookmarks as you had suggested, exporting my passwords using password export addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/ and then re-installing firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by exporting the bookmarks as shown here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer

(suggested by @dwightk )

Exporting my passwords using password export addon 
http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter

and then re-installing firefox.